# React Native Button Not Visible Android

Tags: react-native

Button is not visible in the android.

**Render Method:**

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style = { styles.container }>
            <View style = { styles.form }>
                <Image source={require('../../assets/icon.png')} style = {styles.loginIcon}/>
                <View style = { styles.form }>
                    <TextInput style={ styles.input } onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})} placeholder="Username"/>
                    <TextInput style={ styles.input }  onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})} placeholder="Password"/>
                    <View style={ styles.buttonView }>
                        <Button title="Login" color="#197DC1" style={ styles.primaryBttn } onPress={this.validateCredentialsAndLogin.bind(this)}/>
                    </View>
                    <Text>
                        Forgot Password?
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

**CSS**:

```
 container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ECF0F1'//#F5FCFF
},

form :{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    marginTop: '25%',
    marginBottom:'25%',
    paddingTop:'10%',
    width:'90%',
    height:'40%'
},
input:{
    height:40,
    marginBottom:10,
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    width:'100%'
},
loginIcon:{
    width:80,
    height:80,
},
buttonView:{
    flex:1,
    width:'100%',
    height:50
}
```

Even though there is flex for parent and height and color for button still not able to view button.
PS: I am new to react-native correct me If I am wrong with the styles or anything else.

Comment: Stylesheet seems to be the problem. Its best to start react native development with some understanding about how flexbox works.
check this article on how flexbox works : https://medium.com/@drorbiran/the-full-react-native-layout-cheat-sheet-a4147802405c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like issue is with your styling. You can see your button simply replacing your form style with following:

```
form:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    width:'90%',
    height:'40%'
  },
```

You should first learn how to style using [flexbox(link)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html).